# How to capture Filename Expansion? (expanding globs)

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, wildcard, glob

--**Disclaimer**--
I am open to better titles for this question.

I am trying to get the full name of a file matching: `"target/cs-*.jar"`.
The glob is the version number.
Right now the version is `0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`.
So, below, I would like `jar_location` to evaluate to `cs-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

I've tried a few solutions, some of them work, some don't and I'm not sure what I'm missing.

**Works**
`jar_location=( $( echo "target/cs-*.jar") )
echo "${jar_location[0]}"`

**Doesn't work**
`jar_location=$( echo "target/cs-*.jar")
echo "$jar_location"`

`jar_location=( "/target/cs-*.jar" )
echo "${jar_location}"`

`jar_location=$( ls "target/cs-*.jar" )
echo "${jar_location}"`

--**EDIT**--
Added Filename Expansion to the title
Link to [Bash Globbing / Filename Expansion](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html)
Similar question: [The best way to expand glob pattern?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34011/the-best-way-to-expand-glob-pattern)

Comment: `jar_location=( target/cs-*.jar )` without `echo` and no quotes. Use `shopt -s nullglob` (or `shopt -s failglob`) in case there are no matches.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: Is `Filename Expansion` what I should have been googling for?

Comment: would've been a good start…

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: Is relying on bash globbing bad practice?

Comment: Oh no, globs are wonderful!

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: Ok, thank you for your help. Feel free to post your solution and I'll mark as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using bash, the best option is to use an array to expand the glob:

```
shopt -s nullglob
jar_locations=( target/cs-*.jar )
if [[ ${#jar_locations[@]} -gt 0 ]]; then
    jar_location=${jar_locations##*/}
fi
```

Enabling `nullglob` means that the array will be empty if there are no matches; without this shell option enabled, the array would contain the literal string `target/cs-*.jar` in the case of no matches.

If the length of the array is greater than zero, then set the variable, using the expansion to remove everything up to the last `/` from the first element of the array. This uses the fact that `${jar_locations[0]}` and `$jar_locations` get you the same thing, namely the first element of the array. If you don't like that, you can always assign to a temporary variable.

---

An alternative for those with GNU find:

```
jar_location=$(find target -name 'cs-*.jar' -printf '%f' -quit)
```

This prints the filename of the first result and quits.

Note that if there is more than one file found, the output of these two commands may differ.

Comment: `${#jar_locations[@]}` => Why is there a `#` before `jar_locations` ?

Comment: That's the syntax to get the length of the array.